# closed form expression for the summation $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\binom{i+k}{i}x^ii^t$

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, binomial-coefficients, stirling-numbers, analytic-combinatorics

I’m trying to find a closed form expression for this summation.

$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\binom{i+k}{i}x^ii^t$

Where k and t are given nonnegative integers. According to ( [Checking Jaynes' formula 6.108 for $\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty{m+a \choose m} m^nx^m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2499494/checking-jaynes-formula-6-108-for-sum-limits-m-0-inftyma-choose-m-mnx) ) the answer is

${(x\frac{d}{dx})}^t\frac{1}{{(1-x)}^{k+1}}$

And based on ([What's the property of this series? Is it special? Coefficients of $\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^n f(x) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1450720/whats-the-property-of-this-series-is-it-special-coefficients-of-leftx-frac)) we can write

$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\binom{i+k}{i}x^ii^t=\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^t\frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)^{k+1}}=\sum_{r=1}^{t}{S\left(t,r\right)x^r\frac{d^r}{dx^r}\frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)^{k+1}}}
=\sum_{r=1}^{t}{S\left(t,r\right)x^r\frac{\left(k+1\right)\left(k+2\right)\ldots\left(k+r\right)}{\left(1-x\right)^{k+r+1}}}
=\frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)^{k+1}}\sum_{r=1}^{t}{(k+1)(k+2)...(k+r)\ S\left(t,r\right)\ {(\frac{x}{1-x})}^r}$

Where $S(t,r)$ is the Stirling number of the second kind. This can be written in two ways. But none of them seems simpler to me.

$=\frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)^{k+1}}\sum_{r=1}^{t}{\frac{(k+r)!}{k!}\ S\left(t,r\right)\ {(\frac{x}{1-x})}^r}$

Or since it includes a [falling factorial](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number%23Expansions_of_falling_and_rising_factorials&ved=2ahUKEwjFg-2R4JnrAhXE_qQKHfacCfoQygQwAXoECAEQEw&usg=AOvVaw2j0syNVTmRDcFFC7_e3YcW) ($\left(k+r\right)_{\bar{r}}$), we can write

$=\frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)^{k+1}}\sum_{r=1}^{t}{\sum_{u=0}^{r}{S\left(t,r\right)\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^rs\left(r,u\right)\left(k+r\right)^u}\ }$
$=\frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)^{k+1}}\sum_{r=1}^{t}{\sum_{u=1}^{r}{S\left(t,r\right)\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^rs\left(r,u\right)\left(k+r\right)^u}\ }$
$=\frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)^{k+1}}\sum_{u=1}^{t}{\sum_{r=u}^{t}{S\left(t,r\right)s\left(r,u\right)\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^r\left(k+r\right)^u}\ }
$

Where $s(r,u)$ is the signed Stirling number of the first kind (Remember $\sum_{r=u}^{t}{S\left(t,r\right)s\left(r,u\right)=\delta_{tu}}$ but this one is more complicated).
The question has not been solved yet (finding a closed form expression for this summation.
$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\binom{i+k}{i}x^ii^t$). Can you help me?

(I wrote what I've tried since it may inspire you).

Comment: I suspect you have it in simplest form. Also not sure what the downvote is for.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Mathematica to verify the result for some cases:

```
f[inputT_] := 
 Sum[Binomial[i + k, i]*x^i*i^t /. {t -> inputT}, {i, 0, Infinity}]
f /@ Range[1, 5]
```

For $t=1$,

$$
\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} \tbinom{i+k}{i}x^i i^1= \frac{(k+1) x (1-x)^{-k}}{(x-1)^2}
$$

For $t=2$,

$$
\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} \tbinom{i+k}{i}x^i i^2 = -\frac{(k+1) x (1-x)^{-k} (k x+x+1)}{(x-1)^3}
$$

For $t=3$,

$$
\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} \tbinom{i+k}{i}x^i i^3 =\frac{(k+1) x (1-x)^{-k} \left(k^2 x^2+2 k x^2+3 k x+x^2+4 x+1\right)}{(x-1)^4}
$$

For $t=4$,

$$
\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} \tbinom{i+k}{i}x^i i^4=  \, _4F_3(2,2,2,k+2;1,1,1;x) \cdot (k+1) x
$$

For $t=5$,

$$
\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} \tbinom{i+k}{i}x^i i^5= \, _5F_4(2,2,2,2,k+2;1,1,1,1;x) \cdot (k+1) x
$$

For $t=6$,

$$
\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} \tbinom{i+k}{i}x^i i^6=  \, _6F_5(2,2,2,2,2,k+2;1,1,1,1,1;x) \cdot (k+1) x
$$

---

Here the involved hypergeometric function is [`HypergeometricPFQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v13/ref/HypergeometricPFQ.html.en).

$_p F_q(a ; b ; z)$  has series expansion
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(a_1\right)_k \ldots\left(a_p\right)_k /\left(b_1\right)_k \ldots\left(b_q\right)_k z^k / k !$$

where $(a)_k$  is the Pochhammer symbol.

Comment: As you say, I can (and did) check up to $t=3$, but you and Mathematica lose me at
 $_4F_3(2,2,2,k+2;1,1,1;x)$.  I gather it's the generalized hypergeometric function and involves an infinte sum using the Pochhammer symbol for rising factorials.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question because I am reading Jaynes Chapter 6 and encountered 6.108.  Using your variables, it says
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\binom{i+k}{i}x^ii^t = (x\frac{d}{dx})^t \frac{1}{{(1-x)}^{k+1}}$$
I do not believe a simple closed form expression exists for arbitrary non-negative integers. Of course, for t = 0, it says
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\binom{i+k}{i}x^i = \frac{1}{{(1-x)}^{k+1}}$$
which is the negative binomial expansion of $(1-x)^{-(k+1)}$.  This is what Jaynes uses in the rest of Chapter 6.  He doesn't need $t>0$.

I haven't seen where Jaynes uses $t > 0$, but [Blitzstein](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VmkAAGOYCTORq1wxSQqy255qLJjTNvBI/view) and Hwang (p. 173) use $t > 0$ but $k =0$ when finding the moments of a random variable $Y$ that has the geometric probability distribution with 'failure' probability $x$, $0 \le x \le 1$: $P(Y=i) = (1-x)x^i$.
$$E(Y) = (1-x)\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}ix^i$$
Ignoring the $(1-x)$ out front, they use
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty ix^{i} = \left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)\frac{1}{1-x} =  \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$
and $E(Y) = x/(1-x)$.
$$E(Y^2) = (1-x)\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}i^2x^i$$
Again, ignoring the $(1-x)$ out front, they use
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}i^2x^i = \left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^2\frac{1}{1-x} =  \frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}$$
and $E(Y^2) = \frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^2}$.

It appears that this process of differentiating and then replenishing the supply of $x$'s is standard to calculate sums of the form
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}i^tx^i = \left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^t\frac{1}{1-x}$$
One could continue for $t = 3, 4, ...$, but still $k=0$.
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}i^3x^i = \left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^3\frac{1}{1-x} =  \frac{x(x^2 + 4x +1)}{(1-x)^4}$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}i^4x^i = \left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^4\frac{1}{1-x} = \frac{x(x^3 + 11x^2 + 11x +1)}{(1-x)^5}$$

Jaynes's general summation formula 6.108 combines the above with the negative binomial expansion of $(1-x)^{-(k+1)}$ to get
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\binom{i+k}{i}x^ii^t = (x\frac{d}{dx})^t \frac{1}{{(1-x)}^{k+1}}$$

For $k\ge 0$ and $t=1$, the closed form expression is

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \binom{i+k}{i} ix^{i} = \left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)\frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+1}} =  \frac{x(k+1)}{(1-x)^{k+2}}$$

For $k\ge 0$ and $t=2$, the closed form expression is

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \binom{i+k}{i} i^2x^{i} = \left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)\frac{x(k+1)}{(1-x)^{k+2}} = \frac{x(k+1)(kx+x+1)}{(1-x)^{k+3}}$$

For $t=3$, it's

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \binom{i+k}{i} i^3x^{i} = \left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)\frac{x(k+1)(kx+x+1)}{(1-x)^{k+3}} = \frac{x(k+1)\left((k+1)^2x^2+(3k+4)x+1)\right)}{(1-x)^{k+4}}$$

For $t=4$, it's
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \binom{i+k}{i} i^4x^{i} = \frac{x(k+1) \left((k+1)^3x^3+(6k^2+16k +11)x^2 + (7k+11)x + 1)\right)}{(1-x)^{k+5}}$$

Here, I have provided closed form expressions for all integers $k \ge 0$ and t = 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4.

Comment: Is $(x\frac d{dx})^t=x^t\frac{d^t}{dx^t}$ or what exactly?

Comment: $(x\frac{d}{dx})$ means take the derivative then multiply by $x$.  $(x\frac{d}{dx})^t$ repeat this process $t$ times: derivative, multiply, derivative, multiply, ...